# Removing text in HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, text, html5-canvas

I'm working on a HTML5 Canvas project and have some text drawn on the screen. Right now, it appears and just stay there, but what I need is for it  to disappear after a few seconds so that every time it's called it's not just new text being drawn on top of the old text.

I tried clearRect() but that completely clears the entire rectangle and removes some of my background too, which I don't want.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm drawing the text with this basic function:

```
    function drawText() {

        ctx.font = "30px Arial";
        ctx.fillText("Please wait...", 575, 130);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="showTheText()">Click to show text</button>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      
      function showTheText() {
        var myText = {
          text: 'Hello World',
          x: 0,
          y: 75,
          fill: 1
        };

        drawText(myText, context);

        // wait one second before starting animation
        setTimeout(function() {
          animate(myText, canvas, context);
        }, 1000);
      }

      function drawText(myText, context) {
        context.font="30px Arial";
        context.fillStyle="rgb(0, 0, 0, " + myText.fill + ")";
        context.fillText(myText.text, myText.x, myText.y);
      }
      function animate(myText, canvas, context) {
        // clear
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        // !!!!!!!! redraw your background !!!!!!!!

      // then redraw your text with new opacity
        myText.fill -= .1;
        drawText(myText, context);

        // request new frame
        if (myText.fill > -.1) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            animate(myText, canvas, context);
          }, 2000 / 60);
        }
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this can help you. What it does it immediately draws the text (and the rest of your background, you didn't provide it), then sets up a recursive timeout that will clear the rect, redraw your background, decrement the amount of opacity to apply to the text's fill, and redraw the text as well. You can slow it down by changing the time of the last setTimeout.

I adapted it from this example: https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-animation-stage/

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response. I adapted the code a little bit as I only want the text to be displayed when a particular item on my canvas is clicked. Now the text gets drawn and removed once, but if I click the item again after that, it no longer appears. Any advice on this?

Comment: It is hard to help without seeing your code. Post it here and I'll look it over.

Comment: I've updated my answer so that the text is drawn and fades every time a button is clicked. I have a feeling your "myText" variable is outside the scope of a function, and so it's fill property is being reduced to 0 and never reset back to 1.

Also, if you need to prevent the drawing of two texts at the same time, you could validate the call to "animate" within showTheText's setTimeout. Basically, set a boolean to false after it is called and toggle it to true once the recursive fading completes.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be working fine now. What I am noticing is that there is a split second where the canvas is blank in between clearing it and redrawing the background. Do you know if it would be possible to keep the text on a separate canvas so that only the text gets cleared, and thus avoiding that flash of empty canvas?

Comment: I have seen mentionings of using two canvases on top of one another, so the canvas on the bottom would be the static background and the canvas on top would be the same background with the text drawn onto it. I believe if you search for something like that, you'll find other answers already on stackoverflow explaining how to do that.

You may also want to consider using svg elements instead of trying to draw this manually on the canvas. Your objective seems simple enough that it wouldn't need specific benefits from canvas. Svg elements are dom elements that can be manipulated by ordinary css.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've drawn text to canvas, it's no longer text - it's just a bunch of pixels! Since those pixels overwrite what is already there, there's no way to delete just the text.

Generally what you can do is re-draw the entire scene without the text, if you want to get rid of it.

You could also try re-drawing the text in the same position using the background color, which would remove the text, but this only works if the text is on a solid background.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a simple function to delete ,
you will need some values. For example, font height. width of character ... etc , 
for example in this case , you can use the following function , With few modifications :

```
    function removeText(x,y,txt_length,font_height,char_width,ctx) {
        ctx.clearRect(x, y-font_height ,char_width*txt_length,font_height);
    }
```

and this function for write your string :

```
        function drawText(x,y,text,ctx) {
        ctx.font = "30px Arial";
        ctx.fillText(text,x,y);
        }
```

The same **parameters** `x` and `y` are passed to the functions and `txt_length = text.length;`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected use below option of fillStyle in clearText function

1. Create another function clearText with fillStyle white color with same text and x , y coordinates
2. Call clearText function from the drawText

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawText() {
   clearText()
        ctx.font = "30px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillText("Please wait...", 575, 130);
    }

 function clearText() {
        ctx.font = "30px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText("Please wait...", 575, 130);
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="drawText()">draw text</button><br>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
```

**[codepen](https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oqOXxz)**